# Apache Hadoop 2.6: Pseudo Distribution Mode Setup

Tags: apache, hadoop

I am setting up Apche Hadoop 2.6 for the Psuedo Distributed Operation by following the instructions provided in the link:

```
http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html
```

I am facing an issue after I execute the command:  `$ bin/hdfs dfs -put etc/hadoop input`

The error message is: `put:'input': No such file or directory`

How to resolve this?

Also, I have edited the `hadoop-env.sh` with the statement: `export HADOOP_PREFIX=/usr/local/hadoop`, but cannot  understand that why shell prints out the warning: `/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hadop-env.sh: line 32: export:='/usr/local/hadoop': not a valid identifier`

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this problem.

I created the directory: `$ bin/hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/root` and the problem got solved, as I was logged in as the root in ubuntu. Earlier, I was giving wrong username, hence, facing the issue.

Comment: Setting permissions with hadoop worked for me. Look at your current user (root, peter ...) and set permissions accordingly

`sudo -u <user> bin/hadoop fs -chown <user> /user/<user>`
`bin/hdfs dfs -put etc/hadoop input`